# Parse String into list of items in .NET

Tags: .net, string, parsing

What is the fastest way (fastest to execute) to parse the following String into a list of Integers values?
I need the values that are specified between the # # marks.

```
"#1#+#2#+#3#*1.23+#4#/2+#5#"
```

The above String should create a list of Integers:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5

Comment: fastest? fastest to code or fastest to execute? unless you have very specific requirements, I'd personally go for the most readable solution. e.g.: The String.Split() might arguably be faster than the regex but the regex solution is way more readable (and reliable IMO, but that's arguable too).

Comment: Just split the string using `Split` function. But to remove the special characters or just to get the numeric values you can use regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expressions...

```
var input = "#1#+#2#+#3#*1.23+#4#/2+#5#";

var matches = Regex.Matches(input, "#(.*?)#")
                   .Cast<Match>()
                   .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                   .ToList();

matches.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Fiddle: http://dotnetfiddle.net/GMqhXZ

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.Split` to split your values into an array of strings, and then parse them with `int.Parse` for integers or `double.Parse` for floating-point values.

If that is your input, you may have to also call `Trim` on your strings with the characters you want to remove, e.g. `'*', '/', '+'`.

Answer (score 1):

May be this?

```
var array = Regex.Matches("#1#+#2#+#3#*1.23+#4#/2+#5#", @"(?<=#)\d+(?=#)")
                  .Cast<Match>()
                  .Select(x => x.Value)
                  .ToArray();
```

This checks whether `#` comes before and after a number, if yes matches it.

Here is the [**ideone demo**](http://ideone.com/DStzDy)

Comment: @Serge-appTranslator Just check the output in demo link.

Comment: @Downvoter care to comment? I added a link to working demo also!

Comment: Ha, you fixed it while I was typing ;-) FWIW, I am not the downvoter.

Answer (score 0):

The most readable solution would be something like

```
  string text = "#1#+#2#+#3#*1.23+#4#/2+#5#";
  foreach (string fragment in text.Split('#'))
  {
    int number;
    if (int.TryParse(fragment, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out number))
    {
       Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
 }
```

Maybe a faster implementation can be found - but if you do not have to parse several million numbers, I would prefer a readable solution.