# Replace String characters

Tags: .net, string, replace

I have a String

```
"#1#+#2#+#3#*1.23+#4#/2+#5#"
```

And I have a List of objects as

- 1, "ABC"
- 2, "DEF"
- 3, "GHI"
- 4, "JKL"
- 5, "MNO"

I need a new String where the #1# is replaced with "ABC", #2# replaced with DEF etc.

The desired String:

```
"ABC+DEF+GHI*1.23+JKL/2+MNO"
```

**How to get the replacements executed effectively?**

EDIT: Currently I am looping For Each in the list and using Replace for the string but I believe it is not very memory-efficient. There must be a better way.

Comment: What about iterating over your list and calling `string.Replace` for each item? Have you tried that? Have you tried something else?

Comment: @Jon _effectively_ is the key word. Multiple replacements result in multiple temporary strings and a big waste of memory and CPU due to garbage collection.

Comment: Why not replace #1# with .NET's placeholders, eg {0}, {1}? In this case you could simply use String.Format to do the replacement

Comment: Perhaps there is an external constraint on the formatting of the string.

Comment: @Panagiotis premature optimization. Also effectively != efficiently, and efficiency is usually used as buzzword in situations like this. _"big waste of memory and CPU"_ is pretty relative and most likely not even noticeable.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: You just slated Jon for suggesting using Replace, and then you go an suggest Replace + String.Format?

Comment: Has that already been answered in your question [parse-string-into-list-of-items-in-net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089103/parse-string-into-list-of-items-in-net)?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: *What have you tried?* is they key phrase. You might not have recognized it because I was trying to not put the OP off and instead be constructive. Also, "effectively" is meaningless without context and one of the top words that people just paste into their questions because that will surely get them the best possible answer, right?

Comment: How many of these replacements you need to do ? What is your "good enough" timing ? 1ms per replacement? You sure this is your bottleneck ?

Comment: @musefan I think he meant that the original string be changed such that it has `{1}` rather than `#1#`. Not that the code does a `string.Replace` followed by `string.Format`

Comment: @musefan Perhaps it wasn't clear - use {0} instead of #1#, not replace then String.Format.

Comment: @CodeCaster Not premature at all. If this is a frequent call or a lot of data (thus the need for efficiency), the temporary strings are a real killer. It's such a common gotcha that Ayende uses it as an [interview question](http://ayende.com/blog/165313/the-cost-of-working-with-strings)

Comment: @Panagiotis "frequent" as in you'll start to notice it once you do it hundreds of thousands of times per second. I perfectly understand string semantics, but OP doesn't really come off as a seasoned developer who wishes to push the most string mutations per second out of their machine.

Comment: I edited my question what I currently do...

Comment: _"I believe it is not very memory-efficient"_ - please explain more of your scenario and why you believe so. Do you _have_ problems with your current implementation? How many strings do you want to process? What alternatives have you tried?

Comment: With For Each and Replace it creates a new String for every replacement, right? Number of Strigs here is not enormous though.

Comment: @OP: there is almost always a "better way". The question is if it makes sense in your case to complicate things and to it the better way? It is fairly common that better performing code is also more complicated to write and maintain. Often the simplest way is also "good enough".

Comment: Have you tried to use something like Parallel.For or Parallel.ForEach ? That way you can process these string on multiple cores/threads at same time and get additional performance (better use resources of your HW).

Comment: @OP How many replacements do you have to do? Do you have to use a single template on a large number of lists or do you have to use a large number of templates? In the first case, replacing the placeholders once allows you to use String.Format many times and it's much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is not a huge issue, you may want to use Regular Expressions:

```
string input = "#1#+#2#+#3#*1.23+#4#/2+#5#";
var replaces = new List<string> { "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO" };

string result = Regex.Replace(input, "#[0-9]+#", match => 
{
    string number = match.Value.Substring(1, match.Value.Length - 2);
    int index = int.Parse(number) - 1;
    return replaces[index];
});
```

It works even if the numbers between the '#':

- are not in order
- occur multiple times
- have more than one digit

The number N between the '#' must correspond to the (N-1)-th index in the `replaces` list.
You may want to add some error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Read this line from database. Read it and go changing the # for { or }. If is the first #, then {, if it´s the second }, and so on. Then the result will be something like the text variable below ;)

```
string text = "{0}+{1}+{2}*1.23+{3}/2+{4}";
```

and you have an array with:

```
string[] replaces = {"ABC",
"DEF",
"GHI",
"JKL",
"MNO"};
```

you can do soemthing like:

```
string result = string.Format(text, replaces);
```

Comment: First string comes from database, so I do not build it. I might however here be able to get changes directly to database. Order of these integers is not always 0,1,2... but can by anything

Comment: Then is is build always the same way, you can do something like, with an int, then read the string, if is the first # that you find, change for a {, if is the second change for }, and so on, then the final output will be like the "text" in my answer ;)

Answer (score -1):

Two answers:

1. Simple one. Use `string.Replace(...)` method with each object on your list. But it will be slow on long strings with lots of replacements.
2. Create StringBuilder. Iterate through your string copying chars to stringbuilder until you encounter replacement substring. Insert replacent object in StringBuilder and continue iterating your input string. Return `StringBuilder.ToString()`.

Comment: StringBuilder also has a Replace function, but it just mutates itself rather than creating new copies.

Comment: @ColinMackay still if StringBuilder doesn't have enough capacity before replaces, it will copy string inside it every time its capacity is depleted.

Comment: Yes, but it isn't going to be *every* time. The algorithm to apply more capacity over-provisions the new capacity so that it won't necessarily need to perform a copy the next time. You can also indicate a capacity when creating the StringBuilder if you want to do some extra work by adding up the lengths of the format string and each of the replacement strings, in which case it won't need to do any copying of its internal buffer to a new bigger buffer.

Comment: @ColinMackay Yes it will be for the best to calculate the growth of string (3*replacements objects count) then create string builder with enough capacity. So the string will be copied only two times full (in and out of stringbuilder) and 'objects count' times her tail will be moved.